# Which design pattern to use (i need something like mediator pattern)?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I have a GUI application with a lot of controlles. The most part of them have events and controles are logically wired to each there. 
For example, i have 5 comboBoxes. 
If i choose something in **cb1** and **cb3** them **cb2** must change a list of its available values.
If i choose something in **cb2** and **ch4**, them **cb5** must load its list of its available values.
All the articles i've found in the web says i should use *mediator pattern* in this case.
But in all of these articles mediator - is something like a god class, which knows everything about all controlles and decides what should be done in case of some event.
If i have 5-6 controlles - everything is ok. 
But what if i have something like 20 or 40 controlles? I guess mediator class will become a monster in this case. It'll be hard to do something with it (modify, or add new functionality).

Is there any other patterns, or good examples of mediator pathern, which will help to solve this situation?

PS: Sorry if there are already existing questions on this topic - there are so many questions with the same name, that it not so easy to find something i really need from all these topics.

Comment: Indeed 20-40 controls could lead to a very complex Mediator. However, the Mediator has a clear responsibility, which is easier to understand than spreading out the logic over many classes. The *red flag* in your question is not the risk of god-class due to 20-40 controls, but rather a GUI design that allows 20-40 controls in the first place.

Comment: **Fuhrmanator**, i have a situation with a large form for working with some bussiness documents (invoices, contracts and so on). So, there are a lot of fields, which users have to work with. For the users it is more convenient to work with one screen of information. So, if i'll try to say something like "ok, for now you'll have 3\5 forms\screens\windows. Fill this information in the first one, and that information in the second one." users will find some other developer\company, rather then change there habits. And, anyway, this theme is for another topic, i guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediator is indeed the right choice here, however there is alternative option to use OBSERVER pattern which will allow you to keep logic separate. (cb2 observes cb1 and reacts approperly, cb3->cb2 etc).

With OBSERVER pattern you will have to link only 2 controls at a time, this is like chain.

Answer (score 1):

Use the different actions as strategies [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Example) and invoke a certain strategy from the **Mediator**, so that you would only need to change few lines of code if you need to add more controllers tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try to group the components which belong together in custom components (extending JComponent or JPanel). These custom components listen for the events of their children and update the other children as necessary (-> they become the Mediators). The custom components can also fire their own custom events and thus inform their parent Mediator.

Answer (score 0):

[Mediator pattern - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

If from wikipedia but it's simple and makes it easy to understand.

When I used to study patterns this code was the best one. Simple by yet efficient... And yes for what you are describing i'd use a **Mediator pattern**

Answer (score 0):

gof book says:

" ... Related Patterns

Facade (185) differs from Mediator in that it abstracts a subsystem of objects to provide a more convenient interface. Its protocol is unidirectional; that is, Facade objects make requests of the subsystem classes but not vice versa. In contrast, Mediator enables cooperative behavior that colleague objects don't or can't provide, and the protocol is multidirectional.

Colleagues can communicate with the mediator using the Observer (293) pattern. ... ".

i suspect that a combination of observer and either mediator or facade will work well.

remember that one of the qualities of design patterns is that every time you implement one they are different.